# Did Lord Krishna suffer pain?

Tags: krishna

[This video talks about how Sri Krishna mentions the way life was unfair to him](https://youtu.be/Rxdi3Iaoq68)

Is this a true conversation?Did Lord Krishna “suffer” in these circumstances?As most of the mentioned instances were His destiny,so.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37774/did-lord-krishna-cry-ever

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/can-anyone-control-krishna

Comment: Suffering (दुःख) is always personal, we make hardships (कष्ट /पीड़ा) in our life as Sufferings (दुःख). Krishna is not a "normal human", he's the *Yogeshwara* (योगेश्वर) - one who's unaffected on the inside by the externl material problems. Sure, he did face hardships, but him being the Master of Yoga, he could never have experienced them as suffering - that's what True *Yogis* can do. The lecturer is a *bhakta* of the *BhagwAn* and in *bhakti-rasa* the devotee imagines on themselves what the Lord might have experienced if they were a "normal-human"  too. That's what is implied by in the Video.